# Need JS to modify the element following the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a report authoring tool that lets me add descriptive text in the report header, prior to a table containing the data.  The examples included with the tool show how include Javascript in the description for various special effects.  I would like to change certain cells in the table into links to other reports.  Here's the HTML produced by the reporting tool.

```
<div class="element-info">
  <div class="description">My Description</div>
  <div class="properties">
    <table>...</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried replacing "My Description" with the following, but (perhaps unsurprisingly) it's changing something other than the table.

```
<div>My Description
<script type="text/javascript">
// currentScript is supported in my version of Firefox.
var me = document.currentScript;
// go up two levels to get the enclosing div
var element_info = me.parentElement.parentElement;
// from there we want the properties div, then the table
var mytable = element_info.lastChild.firstChild;
mytable.style.color = "red";
</script>
</div>
```

I expect that the problem is that when the script runs, the HTML in the following div has not yet been parsed.  Mozilla says that the defer attribute will be ignored in scripts without a src= attribute, and I've verified that it does nothing.

Although my example code is using plain Javascript, the authoring tool is based on jQuery, so it's full repertoire is available if needed.

Comment: I'd suspect that (part of) the problem is that `element_info.lastChild.firstChild` will refer to the line-break/empty textNode that comes before the `<table>` element. I'd suggest: `console.log(mytable)` to verify that you're actually targeting the table element. And you're correct that the elements you're targeting don't exist as yet. So why not put the `<script>` *after* the `<table>` to which it refers? Or use the `onload`/`load` event of the `<body>` element to trigger the script to run?

Comment: Good point about the textNode.  I hadn't thought of that.  I'd *love* to put the code after the table, but the only place i can inject it is in the description div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem involves the fact that the html hasn't yet been parsed, you can *immediately* gain a reference to the script, but only *later* utilize it, once the document is loaded. It would look like this:

```
<div>My Description
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the reference immediately...
    var script_of_interest = document.currentScript;

    // And only use it once everything is loaded:
    window.onload = function() {
        var element_info =  script_of_interest.parentElement.parentElement;
        var mytable = element_info.lastChild.firstChild;
        mytable.style.color = "red";
    };
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea!  I was nibbling around the edges, but hadn't figured out all the details (such as they are).  Expect to see this accepted in the next day or so.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your the node your script operates on is loaded before the execution, otherwise your the node may be undefined or just nothing. You may try wrap your code with 
`$(document).ready(function(){
     //your code
})`.